# XNA spritebatch.Draw: Which part gets colored by the color parameter?

Tags: xna, c#, 2d, textures

Which part gets colored and how can I control it?
I have a rounded block and my goal is to have the center filled with a certain color chosen by that parameter. Here's the picture:

[image]

When I draw it with Color.Red for example, just nothing happens. 
Simply creating the texture in these colors I need won't help, I want to create the colors very dynamic. That's a very simply texture but I also want to apply it on harder ones.

The center is transparent already.

Answer (score 2):

What you would do in this case, is draw a colored rectangle behind this texture first, and then draw this texture on top of the colored texture.  This is assuming the center portion of your graphic is transparent.

```
SpriteBatch.Draw(BlankTexture, new Rectangle(Area, Of, Your, Texture), null, YourColor, 0, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
SpriteBatch.Draw(YourTexture, new Rectangle(Area, Of, Your, Texture), null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, 0)
```

Just make sure your BlankTexture is white, and it should draw to whatever color you specify in your Spritebatch draw call.

Comment: This is right. Trying to colour transparency is the problem. No matter what colour you make it, it's going to be invisible.

Comment: This works very well on simple shapes, but what about a triangle?
I figured out changing the center color to something non-transparent does change the color - but it also changes the borders.
Two solutions I can think about is setting the color manually with setData or creating a "mask" texture. The mask represents these parts which should get colored inside and gets drawn above the object - and setting the color there should work.
On setData I don't know how much performance it will cost.

Comment: The mask option is the better solution.  Quicker, and it is what I would do.

Answer (score 2):

> Which part gets colored and how can I control it?

All of it and you can't unless you make your own shader.

> I have a rounded block and my goal is to have the center filled with a certain color chosen by that parameter.

Tinting will not solve this problem. What you want is *masking* which was covered pretty thoroughly [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38118/best-way-to-mask-2d-sprites-in-xna/38150#38150).