# How to load a simple minimap, and hide the background?

Tags: xna, maps, ui-design

I developed a small and simple 3D games minecraft style. I would add a "MiniMap". Until here everything is fine. I had the idea to load the entire map in the background, and then I added the edge of the minimap over. So I can move the map when the player moves. My problem is that I do not know how to make hidden anything above the minimap.
Have you any idea?

I'm stuck in my development

Here is a schematic of what I would do with my minimap. And hide all that is striped in red, outside the minimap.

Thank a looooot ;-) 
[image]

Comment: You need texture masking: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38118/best-way-to-mask-2d-sprites-in-xna

Comment: Thanks ! It's exactly that . Do you can put this on a answer please ? So i can close this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is texture masking. There is more information about that in this answer:

[Best way to mask 2D sprites in XNA?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38118/best-way-to-mask-2d-sprites-in-xna)