# Overlay partially transparent texture onto another, but not the background

Tags: xna, c#, textures

I'm using XNA and C#.
I have two shapes (texture2ds), and I want to overlay shape 2 (50% transparent square) over shape 1 (opaque circle), but I want to get Option B, not Option A.

I basically want to render only the part of the square that's over the circle, without rendering the rest of the square over the background.

[image]

**EDIT**: Let me clarify why exactly I want to do this. I'm essentially using something like this as cheap shadows on top-down 2d planets. When a moon, planet, and sun are all in a 180 degree line, the moon is expected to be completely shaded. So I want to put a shadow behind the planet that won't cover the background, but when the moon passes under it, it gets shaded black.

Comment: What you want sounds like the [Porter-Duff "atop" operator](http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/2013-03-17_Porter_Duff_Compositing_and_Blend_Modes.html).

Comment: @NathanReed The "Dest Atop" is what I need, unfortunately I don't understand how this could be implemented, if I did I probably wouldn't ask such a simple question. However that was interesting and may be helpful for me in the future when I understand things better, so thanks for that!

Comment: This might help: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38118/best-way-to-mask-2d-sprites-in-xna