# Rendering lighting only on specific objects

Tags: xna, c#, shaders, lighting, monogame

I have done something similar to this in monogame:

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

My question is, what would I have to do to draw that lighting effect **only on the pillar** and not the background ? Is there something like ignoring certain sprites when using BlendState.Additive ? How would that work ? Here is how i'm drawing it now.

```
//draw background
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.Opaque);
spriteBatch.Draw(Background, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();

//draw pillar
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred);
spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, new Rectangle(PillarX, PillarY, Width, Height), Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();

//draw lighting sprite in additive mode
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.Additive);
spriteBatch.Draw(LightTexture, pos, null, Color.OrangeRed, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 
    scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
spriteBatch.End();
```

Edit: Also, apart from the pillar I have as an example, I need to do that for 3D models as well, so would the Stencil Buffer work here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-psuedo-coded:

```
//draw pillar
LightMapTexture.Clear(0,0,0,0); //Transparent everywhere
spriteBatch.Begin(Immediate, Alpha);
spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, new Rectangle(PillarX, PillarY, Width, Height), Color.White);
//Still transparent everywhere except texture; texture may be partially transparent also

customBlendState = new BlendState();
customBlendState.ColorSourceBlend = Blend.DestinationAlpha; //0 everywhere but Texture
customBlendState.AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.DestinationAlpha; //0 everywhere but Texture
customBlendState.ColorDestinationBlend = Blend.One; //Plus what's already there
customBlendState.AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.One; //Plus what's already there
spriteBatch.Begin(Immediate, customBlendState);
spriteBatch.Draw(LightTexture, pos, null, Color.OrangeRed, 0f, Vector2.Zero, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
//Still transparent everywhere except texture
spriteBatch.End(); 

//draw background
spriteBatch.Begin(Immediate, Opaque);
spriteBatch.Draw(Background, Vector2.Zero, Color.White,,,,,,,,1); //Draw at Z=1
spriteBatch.End();
```

The preceeding may not be 100%, but should get you well on your way.
The purpose is to only use LightTexture where DestinationAlpha > 0 (Texture has colored the pixel already).
Be back soon.

Edit: Just for learning, please look at the members of [BlendState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.blendstate_fields.aspx). Use each of them and explain the result of each to yourself. i.e. why you are having the problem you have

Comment: not sure how to translate `float4 sampledLightmapColor = tex2D(lightmap);` to actual code, and how would that work when i'm drawing 3D models ?

Comment: I updated my question to be more understandable

Comment: i didn't have the time yet to check your code, but i also want to add that the light effect that i am trying to do with the sprite i have, is going to be used for 3D models as well, i added that in the question too. ( i am trying to light up 3D cubes in a breakout game, when the ball is close to them, and also the pillar in the left and right side of the screen )

Comment: The light will follow the ball around? If you render your 3D geometery to a texture, you can use the same method to light it, since it is 2D at that point.