# How to mask 2D tile sprites

Tags: 2d, xna, monogame, tilemap

I want to use masking technique to be able to reuse tiles. Basically I have the base texture and an array of masking textures for different corners and positions and want to combine the two to get a new texture.

[image]

I encountered this technique while browsing https://github.com/FergusGriggs/Fegaria-Remastered and want to learn more about it. Any help is appreciated. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Does [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/38118/33287) address your question?

Comment: The question has been answered [here](https://community.monogame.net/t/how-to-mask-2d-tile-sprites/15813)

Comment: @gamer1 Link only answers do not suffice.  I moved your answer to a comment.  Please feel free to create a new answer using the knowledge provided in the link.